# How to always mount a usb stick as read/write

Tags: usb, mount

I have one MacBook pro, one CalDigit T3 Plus dock, and one USB stick.

What I want to do is to use the USB stick to extend the storage capability of the Mac; so the USB stick is plugged in the CalDigit and CalDigit is plugged into my Mac before I start to work.

The problem here is that the USB stick is mounted as read-only when I plug in the CalDigit.

The problem stays even when I set /etc/fstab as follows

```
LABEL=AlexMacExtended none hfs rw,auto
```

The USB stick is formatted as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)".
Right now, if I want to write data to the USB stick, I will manually remount it, which is very exhausting.

If I want to mount the USB stick as read-write every time I plug in the Caldigit, are there some settings I need to make?

Comment: btw, I would never, ever store the only copy of any data on something as fragile as a USB stick. They have a remarkable propensity for just dying, without warning.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the Caldigit. Can you get another USB drive to test whether the same thing happens? Perhaps email Caldigit support and ask if this is a known issue, and what they suggest.

Comment: To echo Tetsujin above, a USB stick is not a very reliable storage medium for irreplaceable data at all. I have one client who lost several months of work on a major novel once when the stick used for a backup just died. (She claimed the re-write of the lost material strengthened the final product, but that's neither here nor there.) Best to use an external USB SSD drive for this purpose. Far more reliable.

Comment: This is not expected behaviour. Do you have another stick/external drive to test if it behaves the same when connected to the dock - or do you have another adapter to test the USB stick with? Have you tried to reformat the stick?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, right now I only have one dock and one USB stick at hand. I have no other devices to test with. I think I need to use one USB SSD disk for a try, which needs another purchase. :(