# How to make my HP USB flash drive (uses APFS) writable?

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, permission

I have this HP USB 32 GB glash drive. When I insert this drive into my Mac via an adapter, I can't copy any files into this.

### This is the info from 'Disk Utility':

[image: USB Drive info]

### This is the 'Get info' popup:

[image]

However I get this error when trying to copy a file:

```
❯ cp ~/Downloads/INV-000068.pdf /Volumes/HANSOLO/
cp: /Volumes/HANSOLO/INV-000068.pdf: Read-only file system

❯ mkdir -p /Volumes/HANSOLO/hello
mkdir: /Volumes/HANSOLO/hello: Read-only file system
```

Although the 'Get Info' popup says, it is 'Read & Write' for my user id, the copy fails with the above error. Also copying via Finder doesn't work (it shows the disabled mouse icon when dragging a file into this volume and no 'Paste' option in the right click menu).

I have already tried a few approaches such as editing `/etc/fstab` as per [How to always mount a usb stick as read/write](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429773/how-to-always-mount-a-usb-stick-as-read-write) but it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

The drive controller has detected write errors and permanently locked the drive to preserve the data. You can't unlock it. Copy the data to another drive and discard this one.

Comment: This is likely true - see https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only for a full workthrough.